# LoadError: cannot load such file -- selenium/webdriver/phantomjs

Tags: ruby, selenium, phantomjs, watir

I have this code in my Cucumber Hooks file to run the ghost driver it was working until yesterday I start seeing the error message:

```
Before do
  Selenium::WebDriver::PhantomJS.path = 'C:\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe'
  @browser = Watir::Browser.start "https://www.google.com",  :phantomjs
  @browser.window.maximize    
end
```

Error message:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- selenium/webdriver/phantomjs
```

Comment: may be the phantom js file is missing or deleted on a given path. Check it again file on a path.

Comment: I have checked it and is there I don't know why is not working.

Comment: open the properties of phantom.js file and check mark the executable.

Comment: I am using Window so I have downloaded the package from here: http://phantomjs.org/download.html It has a file in the \bin folder called phantom.exe this is working. Just couldn't get it to work again from RubyMine.

Comment: Can you give the full exception? Also did you change anything between yesterday and today - eg did you upgrade gems, etc.

Comment: The only message I got is the error message I mentioned in above. I upgraded  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/30a87a31817be9726ce78011d5df9bb4

Answer (score 7):

Yes, we've removed support for PhantomJS as of Selenium 3.8.
The PhantomJS project [is no longer being maintained](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/9aI5d-LDuNE). If you actually do need headless, please investigate either the Chrome or Firefox headless options.

Comment: Is there plans to make the removal more obvious? In the change log, 3.6 added the deprecation message. 3.8 doesn't say anything about removal. Also weird that if support is removed, it's not removed as a valid key in `Selenium::WebDriver.for`?

Comment: Yeah, there's been confusion, we're discussing it in Selenium slack.

Answer (score 5):

For those who encounter this error, you can work around it by locking your selenium-webdriver version in your Gemfile like so:

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.6.0'
```

and then `bundle update` to downgrade.

(You may not even have selenium-webdriver specified in your Gemfile currently if it's just being loaded as a dependency of watir or some other library.)

The long term fix, of course, is to move off of PhantomJS to Chrome or Firefox headless.

Comment: Hi, I have installed the 3.6 version and it worked. I have also tried Chrome and Firefox headless but it does not like url with https. Do you know how to resolve this issue?